# Django ORM alternatives

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

Is there a good feature-wise alternative to the django ORM? Specifically the migrations and the error handling. I am developing an application which is not for the web, so django is overkill.

I am using sqlalchemy at the current time but dislike (or havent found the right groove) some of its behaviors. For example the required rollback after an insert with a pk collision. Or that session.query caches too much.

The migration packages also look too work intensive. Am I making something wrong? I really want to like it but fail to understand the minimalism at some points.

Some code, maybe it helps:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Apartment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'apartment'

    id = Column('id', primary_key=True)
    # address
    street= Column('street', String(128))
    house_number = Column('housenumber', String(32))
    zip = Column('zip', String(16))
    city = Column('city', String(64))
    country = Column('country', String(64))

    def save(self):
        try:
            session.add(self)
            session.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            session.rollback()

    @staticmethod
    def objects():
        return session.query(Apartment)


conn_string = 'postgres://....'
engine = create_engine(conn_string)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

Comment: This is a rather subjective question, but [peewee](https://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a lightweight python ORM

Comment: You are right but I didnt like the way migrations are made.